# How to parallelize Multiple Requests to mongoDb?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I am using a single standalone Mongo DB server with no special topology like replication or sharding etc. Currently I have an issue that mongo DB does not support more than 500 parallel requests. Note that I am using only one instance of MongoClient and the remaining threads are used for inserts. I am using a java executor framework to create the threads and these threads are used to insert data to a collection [all insert in the same collection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should queue the requests before you issue them towards the database. There is no use requesting 500 things from your database in parallel. Remember a single request comes with some costs memory wise, locking wise and so on. Actually you are wasting resources by asking your database too much at once - remember I mean this request wise not data wise.

So use a queue (or more) and pool up the requests. From that pool you feed your worker threads (lets say 5 or 10 are enough) and that's it.

Take a look at the [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface in the concurrent package of java. Using asynchrone processing here looks like the thing with the highest throughput and the lowest resource impact.

But check the MongoDB driver first. I would not be surprised if they have implemented it already this way. If this is the case you just have to limit yourself by using a queue to have only lets say 10 or 100 requests at once being handled by the database driver. Do some performance check tweaking the number of actual requests send to the database.

Comment: Assume that I send parallel request for READ, there should be no locks in that case. What would be the overhead's in case of parallel READ requests.

Comment: MongoDB attaches some sort of overhead to each request memory wise. Depending on what you are up to, sometimes mongodb opens up several documents at once doing things in parallel and also postpone other things.

Do some benchmarking. If you do some inexpensive requests on small documents the footprint is not that much but doing search or subtree reading can be quite costly.

Comment: And mongodb tends to do more things concurrently then you have CPUcores so your additonal requests do no actually speed up things but reduce overall responstime by costing addional memory (ok not much but do some benchmarking to be sure).